# Mobile phone movement in space

Tags: android, ios, gyroscope

is it possible to track mobile phone movement in space? I need and info like:
vertical position of the phone and it's movement in 3d space of our world.
So lets imagine that we are holding phone at 1.5 meters from the ground and moving it by circle trajectory. So I need to get coords of the phone in real word. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to do it like GPS, then you would have to move the z axis onto the x axis. Basically making the 3D element part of the 2D element, then reconstructing the 3d sphere using the newly obtained information to get a position in space. The problem with this method is that the earth is round, and you can never get a view that applies to all the phones.